# How can you run sqlcmd in a batch script with passing variables?

Tags: loops, batch-file, sqlcmd

I'm trying to use a Windows command prompt on Server 2012 R2 to run a batch file with the following command line. I want to run an SQL command (*sqlcmd*) and return the results to the console window.

This is what I'm currently trying, but `sqlcmd` keeps throwing back:

> Sqlcmd: 'test': Invalid argument. Enter '-?' for help.

```
FOR /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %%F IN (`sqlcmd -S localhost -E -i "backup.sql" -v dbname="test"`) DO (
    Echo %%F
)
```

Note: I have also tried to run just this `sqlcmd` command (above) in a command prompt with no issues. It's like it does not like the `FOR /F` loop or something.

However if I try it without parameters/variables it works perfectly!

```
FOR /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %%F IN (`sqlcmd -S localhost -E -i "backup.sql"`) DO (
    Echo %%F
)
```

Does anyone know a way around getting the variables passed to my SQL query using `sqlcmd`, Windows CMD, as well as a `FOR /F` loop such as in my first example?

Comment: You need to escape the equal sign: `^=`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a line batch code is processed it goes through multiple phases, in a specific order. The order of these phases means that in this case your equals character, `=` requires special attention. *For a full explanation on these phases read [this information](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094699/how-does-the-windows-command-interpreter-cmd-exe-parse-scripts/7970912#7970912)*.

Here's two methods, one of which was already given in the comment area.

*I have formatted the command over three lines so that it's clearer, whether you do that too is optional.*

Escape the equals character `=` with a caret `^`:

```bat
For /F "Delims=" %%A In ('
    sqlcmd -S localhost -E -i backup.sql -v dbname^=test
') Do Echo %%A
```

Or if you wish to doublequote your filename and value:

```bat
For /F "Delims=" %%A In ('
    sqlcmd -S localhost -E -i "backup.sql" -v dbname^="test"
') Do Echo %%A
```

---

Surround the command in doublequotes, `"`:

```bat
For /F "Delims=" %%A In ('
    "sqlcmd -S localhost -E -i backup.sql -v dbname=test"
') Do Echo %%A
```

```bat
For /F "Delims=" %%A In ('
    "sqlcmd -S localhost -E -i "back up.sql" -v dbname="my test""
') Do Echo %%A
```

*Please note as shown above, whilst it's probably good practice, Microsoft state, ['File paths that contain spaces must be enclosed in quotation marks' and 'Enclose the value in quotation marks if the value contains spaces'](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility#command-line-options). They were not needed in your case and could have been omitted.*

Comment: It was 100% the carrot that got me.  Thanks!

Comment: To be honest I didn't even use double quotes around my entire command. I do however always try to use them around params when I can, except in rare situations such as robocopy that can freak out with slashes and double quotes. I actually use a fourth way... No double quotes around the entire command and double quotes around the param.

Comment: @Avro, have added that additional scenario to my answer just for completeness.